# Show string resource ID instead of string's value in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-resources

i had set the text programatically but i don't want to see the resource's text("textid, etc"), only the resource (R.id.textid)
See the image below
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61498131/12478830

Comment: @MMG I want to see the resource, not to exract it. but thanks anyway

Comment: i want to see it before i click on it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android Studio go to `File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding -> uncheck "Android String References"`. After reopening the file, string resources should not be previewed.